# How to change the highlighter color circle for radio button on focus

Tags: android, radio-button

I am referring to the transparent gray color that comes on radio button when focused

[image: I am referring to the transparent gray color that comes on radio button when focused]

I tried most of the style attributes with color for the RadioButton.

```xml
    <style name="Widget.App.RadioButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">50</item>
        <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/Red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimarySurface">@color/Green</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_red_800</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_red_400</item>
        <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/md_purple_500</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can set `transparent` background to your `RadioButton` groups.

To do that, you can add this line to your custom style.

```xml
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

So, your custom style will look like this;

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.RadioButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">50</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">#FF3333</item>
    <item name="colorPrimarySurface">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```